# Android + PhoneGap + jQuery Validate - not firing

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-validate

I'm using jQuery Mobile with jQuery Validate. I have multiple forms that post with ajax serialize once all pages have been completed.

The 'next' button below works on iOS and Android when accessed from the native browser. When I package with PhoneGap and run on Android, the validation does not fire. Everything else works fine.

If I remove the valid() condition, the button works as expected. So it must be an issue with how I'm using jQuery Validate.

I've tried shifting the order of things in various ways. I've tried:

```
if (!$("#infofm").valid()) {
```

And

```
if($("#infofm").valid()) {
```

Always the same result - works in native browsers, but not after PhoneGap. I've been struggling with this for a long time now. Here's the relevant code. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

```
$(function(){ 
    $('a#nxt1').bind('click', function(event, ui) {
        infoval();
    });

function infoval(){
    var isvalidate=$("#infofm").valid();
    if(isvalidate) {
        $.mobile.changePage('#towertop', {transition: 'slidefade'});
    } else {
        alert("Please fill in all fields on this page before proceding");
    }
};

$(document).ready( function(){ 
$("#infofm").validate({ errorPlacement: function(error, element) {} }); });
```

AND

```
<a href="" id="nxt1" data-iconpos="bottom" data-theme="a" data-icon="arrow-r">Next Step</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that for jQuery Mobile, you'll need to use....

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
```

instead of

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

See:   http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html

> **Important:** Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')`, not `$(document).ready()`
>
> The first thing you learn in jQuery is to call code inside the
>   `$(document).ready()` function so everything will execute as soon as
>   the DOM is loaded. However, in jQuery Mobile, Ajax is used to load the
>   contents of each page into the DOM as you navigate, and the DOM ready
>   handler only executes for the first page. To execute code whenever a
>   new page is loaded and created, you can bind to the `pageinit` event.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I tried $('#info').on('pageinit', function(){ since that is the name of my JQM page. Worked on browsers, but after PhoneGap now the page just shows the loading spinner indefinitely...

Comment: I don't know much about `PhoneGap`.  I was answering a jQuery Validate question... does that work now at least?

Comment: The issue is jQuery Validate when combined with PhoneGap. Validate was always working for me - just not after the app has been packaged with PhoneGap.

Comment: Well then, I doubt I can be much further help.  I cannot imagine what PhoneGap could be doing here.  Does it change your code somehow?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm using build.phonegap.com, so I don't have a great handle on the process. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @user1911141, I looked at the PhoneGap page. If your code is _"being wrapped with PhoneGap"_ in the cloud, what does that really mean? Surely, there's a way to see what happens to your code with this final wrapped version. You may have to resort to support from PhoneGap if there's nothing specific we can see.

Comment: @Sparky please help me i have done your suggestion but still getting problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164460/validation-in-phonegap-but-works-perfectly-in-browser

Answer (score 0):

My javaScript code was not being called when bundled into a phonegap app (on iOS in my case). I built a web app with multiple screens and buttons that are hidden or displayed depending on user interaction.

When using the iOS simulator bundled with XCode you can see the sourcecode of the generated web app in safari (under the "Develop" menu, developer tools have to be enabled in Safari preferences). In the source code I noticed that the all my apps html pages are merged into one and the only javascript included is from the first page (default index.html) - all other  elements within the page were removed from the file. So I changed

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
       ...
    });
```

to

```
    $(document).on('pageinit', function(){
       ...
    });
```

(thanks Sparky, for your answer above) and added all the jquery js code from the following pages into index.html. As an example I added the following line to hide a div on one of the pages:

```
    $("#cancelButtonDiv").hide();
```

The code is now being executed and the methods specified on my buttons are being called properly.