# Validation is not working in Phonegap but works perfectly in Browser

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a field of type `number` . I have validated this field using `jquery` it shows necessary warnings in browser but failed to show in phone when using it with `Phonegap`.

My code is :

```
PUT YOUR ANSWER HERE: <input id="ans" type="number" name="ans" min="1" max="10">

  <input id="nextbutton1" type="button" name="next1" value="Subbmit" class="nextbutton">
```

I want to accept only numbers from 1 to 10. But when I am entering 1-- or 1 2 or 2++ it takes input without any prompt in phone.

My jquery is this

```
$('#nextbutton1').click(function() {
   var num=$("#ans").val().trim();

                if ((num < 1 || num > 10) && num.length != 0) {
        if (num < 1) {
            alert("Oops! You cannot enter vlues smaller than 1");
          $('input[type=number]').val('');

        }

        if (num > 10) {
            alert("Oops! You cannot enter vlues Greater than 10");
            $('input[type=number]').val('');
        }

    }

else if ((num % 1) != 0) {
    alert("You Cannot Enter Decimal Values or any other symbols ");
    $('input[type=number]').val('');
}
else if(num=="")
{
alert("Oops ! Please Select any number from 1 to 10 ");
$('input[type=number]').val('');
}
else
{
if(num == rand)
{
alert("Correct");
}
}
 });
```

Here rand is random generated number from 1 to 10.

What can i do to work perfectly in phone?

**UPDATE**

I have also done this correction as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528863/android-phonegap-jquery-validate-not-firing) but still not working.

Comment: try using input type="text"...!!

Comment: I am creating this for making android app. If i use text instead of number then on clcking in the text field qwerty kepad will open and i have to write validation code for alphabets too.

Comment: Yah I got your point. I checked your code which is working fine on browsers I dont know why its not working for you on devices.. Just checked it using type="text"..!!

Comment: try using parseInt()..

Comment: I have tried using parseInt() also not working. I am using jquery mobile is that making some kind of problem for my jquery validation?

Comment: instead of $("#ans").val().trim(); try using  $.trim( $("#ans").val());  try putting that in alert and see if you are able to get the value or any error, per my exp it should gie you an error and may be that the reason why its getting break   https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: Also, why dont you use Jquery Validator? why to make ur life difficult writing so many if and else

Comment: I haven't used it because i am not used to it. So i prefer doing it myself the way i want.

Comment: But thats not the proper way of doing it where you can make your life very simple using those plugins!

Comment: I will follow this from now on but please help me how can i fix this error

Comment: I'll create a fiddle using Jquery validator

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/42SQc/1/ try this fiddle and let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Yes it workss @ScorpionRulz just by adding your function on blurr keypress it wokrs fine .

Comment: @ScorpionRulz it will be very helpful if you kindly explain this function then it will make sure i understand it fully.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48943/discussion-between-scorpionrulz-and-insanity)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert value **string** to integer before comparing it with numbers. So correct line would be:

```
var num = window.parseInt($("#ans").val().trim(), 10);
```

Comment: thanks for answering it still not working in android AVD

Comment: I am using jquery mobile is that making some kind of problem for my jquery validation?